# How do I play Do Re Mi Fa etc using just one string?

Tags: guitar, scales

I'm training my voice and need a point of reference.

Comment: I assume that by pressing certain fret on a certain string you get get any of the 7 notes. I am a very beginner with anything musical but that's my understanding

Comment: Well - even if you re-tuned each string of your guitar, you can only get Do-Re-Mi-Fa-So-La out of six strings.  I think it will be easier for you to use my single string approach just for a reference point for singing.  It works the same on any string regardless of how you tune it.  If you want to use all six strings in standard tuning you will only need four strings but will play 2 or 3 notes per string except for the last Do an octave above first Do.

Comment: @RockinCowboy - 0-2-4-5-7-9-11-12 is exactly what I was looking for and my voice teacher (who plays piano so she wasn't sure about guitar) confirmed. I would have marked your response as an answer if  you responded as such :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andrey Glad I could help.  Looks like someone else posted my response as an answer.  But the important thing is, you received the information that was helpful to you.

Comment: You should be learning what notes and intervals are -- the very basics of theory are extraordinarily helpful and at minimum will help you communicate when you encounter an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On guitar, you can use an open string.  Start open ("0"), and use the following pattern:

0 2 4 5 7 9 11 12

The open strings are, from heaviest to lightest, E A D G B E.

You can just add to the above pattern if you want to start on a different fret.  For instance, if you want to use the F# major scale, start on the E string, 2nd fret, and use:
2 4 6 7 9 11 13 14

If you meant something different in your question, please clarify. :)

Answer (score 3):

Repeat after me…

> tone tone semitone… tone tone tone semitone.

That's the first thing I remember being taught about the major scale - the intervals… which you can then apply from any start-point.

semitone = 1 fret
tone = 2 frets